# Undefined symbols for architecture i386 - All items from podfile

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I am getting the below error for Restkit, however reskit is added using cocoapods. I have tried a lot of solutions and can not seem to find the correct one. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Error Message:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/ME/Documents/proj'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-Lcopy/projIOSProjectNew/projIOSWorkspace/projIOSCore/build/Debug-iphoneos'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-Ldev'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-Lnewest/projIOSProjectNew/projIOSWorkspace/Pods/build/Debug-iphoneos'
    Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
      "_AFNetworkingOperationDidFinishNotification", referenced from:
          -[RKObjectRequestOperationLogger init] in libPods-projIOSCore-RestKit.a(RKObjectRequestOperation.o)
      "_AFNetworkingOperationDidStartNotification", referenced from:
          -[RKObjectRequestOperationLogger init] in libPods-projIOSCore-RestKit.a(RKObjectRequestOperation.o)
      "_AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey", referenced from:
          -[RKHTTPRequestOperation error] in libPods-projIOSCore-RestKit.a(RKHTTPRequestOperation.o)
      "_AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey", referenced from:
          -[RKHTTPRequestOperation error] in libPods-projIOSCore-RestKit.a(RKHTTPRequestOperation.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPClient", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in libPods-PROJIOSCore-RestKit.a(RKObjectManager.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestOperation", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in libPods-PROJIOSCore-RestKit.a(RKHTTPRequestOperation.o)
          _OBJC_CLASS_$_RKHTTPRequestOperation in libPods-projIOSCore-RestKit.a(RKHTTPRequestOperation.o)
          objc-class-ref in libPods-PROJIOSCore-RestKit.a(RKObjectRequestOperation.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFJSONRequestOperation", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in libPods-projIOSCore-RestKit.a(RKObjectManager.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in libPods-projIOSCore-RestKit.a(RKObjectRequestOperation.o)
```

Edit: I am also receiving the following warnings which is the files that are missing.

```
d: warning: ld: warning: ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/ME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYWORKSPACE-bceskqnbpsdarjfijbrjozdfciem/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods-RewoIOSCore-ISO8601DateFormatterValueTransformer.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386):
```

Podfile looks as follows:

```
    workspace 'projIOSWorkspace.xcworkspace'
xcodeproj 'projIOSCore/projIOSCore.xcodeproj'
xcodeproj 'projIOS2Project/projIOS2Project.xcodeproj'
xcodeproj 'projmobileiosproject/projIOSProject.xcodeproj'


#source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target :projIOSCore  do
    platform :ios, '8.0'

    pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.24.0'

    xcodeproj 'projIOSCore/projIOSCore.xcodeproj'
end


target :projIOS2Project do
    platform :ios, '8.0'

    pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.24.0'

    # Include optional Testing and Search components
    pod 'RestKit/Testing'
    pod 'RestKit/Search'
    pod 'FMDB'
    pod 'ZBarSDK', '~> 1.3'
    pod 'MZFormSheetController', '~> 2.3'
    pod 'CTCheckbox', '~> 0.0'
    pod 'MGSwipeTableCell', '~> 1.1.1'
    pod 'FormatterKit', '~> 1.7'
    pod 'TSMessages'
    pod 'DLAlertView', '~>1.2.4'
    pod 'SIAlertView', '~> 1.3'
    pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.8'

    xcodeproj 'projIOS2Project/projIOS2Project.xcodeproj'
end

target :projIOSProject do
    platform :ios, '8.0'

    pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.24.0'

    # Include optional Testing and Search components
    pod 'FMDB'
    pod 'ZBarSDK', '~> 1.3'
    pod 'AFPopupView', '~> 1.0'
    pod 'PubNub', '3.6.1'
    pod 'ChameleonFramework'
    pod 'SGActionView', '~> 0.0'
    pod 'RXPromise', '~> 0.13'
    pod 'SWTableViewCell', '~> 0.3.6'
    pod 'UIAlertView+Blocks'
    pod 'CNPPopupController'

    xcodeproj 'projmobileiosproject/projIOSProject.xcodeproj'
end
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing the AFNetworking library.

Comment: it is added using cocoapods @Arkku

Comment: Perhaps it is not added correctly to the project, or the wrong version is added (there was a major API change between versions 1 and 2) – all of the missing symbols are from AFNetworking.

Answer (score 1):

If things have ended up messy, I would try doing a fresh install of your CocoaPods dependencies, using the following steps:

- Check that your Podfile refers correctly to your app's target.
- Open the Build Phases tab of the target and find "Link Binary with Libraries". Remove CocoaPods.

[image]

- Delete the .workspace file
- Delete the Pods/ directory
- Run `pod install` again.

Comment: Can you post your Podfile? Using Objc or Swift?

Comment: using objc for the project - and added pod file